# Image source not updating in tags via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the below code

```
    var imgs = [ "1_CLUB.JPG", "2_CLUB.JPG", "3_CLUB.JPG", "4_CLUB.JPG",
            "5_CLUB.JPG", "6_CLUB.JPG", "7_CLUB.JPG", "8_CLUB.JPG",
            "9_CLUB.JPG", "10_CLUB.JPG", "J_CLUB.JPG", "Q_CLUB.JPG",
            "K_CLUB.JPG",

            "1_HEART.JPG", "2_HEART.JPG", "3_HEART.JPG", "4_HEART.JPG",
            "5_HEART.JPG", "6_HEART.JPG", "7_HEART.JPG", "8_HEART.JPG",
            "9_HEART.JPG", "10_HEART.JPG", "J_HEART.JPG", "Q_HEART.JPG",
            "K_HEART.JPG", "1_SPADE.JPG", "2_SPADE.JPG", "3_SPADE.JPG",
            "4_SPADE.JPG", "5_SPADE.JPG", "6_SPADE.JPG", "7_SPADE.JPG",
            "8_SPADE.JPG", "9_SPADE.JPG", "10_SPADE.JPG", "J_SPADE.JPG",
            "Q_SPADE.JPG", "K_SPADE.JPG",

            "1_DIAM.JPG", "2_DIAM.JPG", "3_DIAM.JPG", "4_DIAM.JPG",
            "5_DIAM.JPG", "6_DIAM.JPG", "7_DIAM.JPG", "8_DIAM.JPG",
            "9_DIAM.JPG", "10_DIAM.JPG", "J_DIAM.JPG", "Q_DIAM.JPG",
            "K_DIAM.JPG",

    ];

    function preloader() {
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            var imageObject = new Image();

            imageObject.src = imgs[i];
            imgs.push(imageObject);

        }

    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("img").src = "\"" + imgs[10] + "\"";
    console.log("\"" + imgs[10] + "\"");
    console.log("<img src=\""+imgs[10]+"\""+"width=\"400px\" height=\"150px\"/>");
```

Output (Showing correctly in console)

[image]

Comment: Why those unnecessary `\"` in `.src = ...` and `console.log("\"" + ... + "\"")?

Comment: That was just a debug check in console  to see if it works with quotes as i wasnt sure earlier what went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("img")` returns an array of dom  elements. If you are sure that there are only one img element in the dom, you can write the code in the following way,

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = 'your img url'
```

For further reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName

Comment: yeah perfect thanks but why it din show me the error of left assignment or right assignent

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Because your script just added a `src` property to the `HTMLCollection` returned by `.getElementsByTagName()` which is totally valid